# Software that can detect spyware and keyloggers

Tags: android, windows-10, antivirus, keylogger, spyware

Are there any software that can detect spyware and keyloggers in my computer?

The program should be able to check any programs that scan key presses and any programs that take screen capture and reports which one are suspicious.

Any such program?

Basically the program should check which programs are taking screenshot or listening to key pressed.

Then the program should compare that to known programs. I think there are very few programs that should legitimately capture keyboard. I actually knows none.

Any such programs?

The program should also check internet connection. Besides firefox, skype, and stuffs, who else should connect to internet?

Any such scanners? Reliable ones that's easy to use? Most importantly I want reliable ones.

I am a bit techie my self.

This one is actually for windows. However, I also uses android and I do not "root" my android. So I do not think I have to worry about virus there.

Comment: At first I was skeptical about this question, but it seems that keylogging detection is a thing, and they run differently from how antivirus programs usually run in normal times, I was tipped by https://security.stackexchange.com/a/23788/634

Comment: You didn't say for what OS it should be – though the `antivirus` tag points to Windows. Could you please add the corresponding tag?